# Any way to control evince settings from the commandline?

Tags: pdf, evince

Is there any way to change / set `evince` settings either in a config file or from the command line when starting ?

I'm using `inotifywait` to display a PDF when it is copied to a specific file, and I want to be able to set zoom (fit to page), continuous scrolling off and dual (side-by-side mode).

I know that I can manually launch `evince`, set these values and save as default, but that only works if someone manually launches it first and does this right - I want to guarantee a certain display at launch time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can control those settings via cli options (I'd love to be proven wrong though...)
You could however set the zoom, dual mode etc via the file attributes<sup>1</sup> *before* launching `evince`. You do that via [`gio`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio.html) `set` so e.g. if you run:

```
gio set myfile.pdf metadata::evince::continuous 0
gio set myfile.pdf metadata::evince::dual-page 1
gio set myfile.pdf metadata::evince::sizing_mode: fit-page
```

and then

```
evince myfile.pdf
```

it should open `myfile.pdf` in dual-mode, with continuous scrolling off and fit-to-page.

---

<sup>1: To see all the attributes run `gio info myfile.pdf`. Note this is rather new stuff - it replaces `gvfs-info` and respectively `gvfs-set-attribute` (which had similar syntax)</sup>

Comment: I'm noticing that gio changes don't seem to take effect immediately. For example, I do gio set myfile.pdf metadata::evince::continuous 0. I then check with gio info myfile.pdf and it's not shown there... wait a while and it is again. What's the best way to sync / flush this ?

Comment: @Anonymouslemming - I cannot replicate that... the change is instantaneous on my system (`gio 2.52.3` on _archlinux_ - the drives are all SSD if it matters...)